# _src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor

Tags: python, opencv

There's nothing wrong in this code except I keep getting this error.

```
rgb_frame =cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-2b5g8ysb\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

I googled this error and they told me to check if the frames are saved well. I checked and it was doing fine. Also they told me to check path `'video3.mp4'`. I saved the video in the same folder as this python file.

Can anyone tell why I keep getting this error?

```
import cv2
import openpyxl


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video3.mp4')    


wb= openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet= wb.active

a=1
b=1


while(1):

     _, frame = cap.read()
    frame_pos=cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)

    #error here!
    rgb_frame =cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    hsv_frame01=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    

    ycrb_frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
    planes=cv2.split(ycrb_frame)
    planes[0]=cv2.equalizeHist(planes[0])
    dst_ycrb=cv2.merge(planes)


    dst=cv2.cvtColor(dst_ycrb,cv2.COLOR_YCrCb2BGR)
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)



    lower_hsv = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, (30, 150, 50), (255, 255, 180))
    upper_hsv = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, (0, 70,100), (10, 255, 255))   
    added_hsv = cv2.addWeighted(lower_hsv, 1.0, upper_hsv, 1.0, 0.0)


    se=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,3))   

    bi=cv2.medianBlur(added_hsv,3)
    dilate=cv2.dilate(bi,se,iterations=6)



    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=dilate)


    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilate,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 


    for i in contours:
        M=cv2.moments(i)     
    
    
        cy=int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        cx=int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
       
        cv2.drawContours(res,[i],0,(255,0,0),3)
        cv2.circle(res,(cx,cy),3,(255,0,0),-1)
   
    
        if frame_pos>=285 and cy<320:
            text1='RGB : ' + str(rgb_frame[cy,cx])
            text2='HSV : ' + str(hsv_frame01[cy,cx])
            cv2.putText(res,text1,(cx-200 ,cy),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1 ,(255,255,255))
            cv2.putText(res,text2,(cx-200 ,cy-30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1 ,(255,255,255))
            if cx<=427:
                sheet.cell(row=a,column=1).value=str(rgb_frame[cy,cx])
                a=a+1
           
                   
            else:
                sheet.cell(row=b,column=2).value=str(rgb_frame[cy,cx])
                b=b+1
           
 
        elif 350<= cy <=400 :    
            text1='RGB : ' + str(rgb_frame[cy,cx])
            text2='HSV : ' + str(hsv_frame01[cy,cx])
        
            cv2.putText(res,text1,(cx-200 ,cy),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1 ,(255,255,255))
            cv2.putText(res,text2,(cx-200 ,cy-30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1 ,(255,255,255))

            if cx<=427:
                sheet.cell(row=a,column=1).value=str(rgb_frame[cy,cx])
                a=a+1
            else:
                sheet.cell(row=b,column=2).value=str(rgb_frame[cy,cx])
                b=b+1 
       
    
    wb.save('1.xlsx')
    cv2.namedWindow('frame',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.namedWindow('added_hsv',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.namedWindow('res',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)


    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('added_hsv',added_hsv)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)

    if cv2.waitKey(5)>0:
        break   

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: probably it had problem to read frame from file and now `frame` is `None` and it can't change colors in `None`. You should run code only in `if frame is not None:`

Comment: maybe use `C:\full\path\to\video3.mp4`. Sometime code can be executed with different "Current Working Direcory" and it may search video in different folder then you expect and it may not find your video.

Comment: @furas I added 'if frame is None: print('image load failed') break ' and I changed path. But the result was weird. I got one 'image load failed' printed out and the 3 windows played perfectly well

Comment: I don't understand why it display windows if you use `break` to exit this loop. Maybe `break` has wrong indentation. You can add more `print()` in other places to see which part is executed - it is called `print debuging` - or learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the answer! The video is made of 290 frames. I tried print debuging and found out that it displayed windows perfectly well  because the 'image load failed' printed  when it was the last frame (290). I still don't understand why the last frame can't convert color.

Comment: maybe it is not last frame but `None` after last frame which inform you that there is no more frames.

Comment: @furas You are really good:) Thank you. Is it okay if I ask you one more problem that I have in this code?

Comment: if you small problem with this code then ask. But if have some bigger problem then you should create new question on new page - you will have more place for code and desciption. And maybe new poeple see it - with new ideas.

Comment: @furas I posted new question on new page. Please check out if you have time! Thanks again!